# Prove $\frac{1}{1+(k+1)^2} \lt \arctan(k+1) - \arctan(k) \lt \frac{1}{1+k^2}, k \in \mathbb N^*$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, definite-integrals

$$f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R, f(x) = \arctan x  $$

$$\frac{1}{1+(k+1)^2} \lt f(k+1) - f(k) \lt \frac{1}{1+k^2}, k\in \mathbb N^*$$
I have to prove this for an exercise and I am would greatly appreciate some help. So far I have tried the following: Noticed that the expression can be written as:
$$f'(k+1) \lt f(k+1) - f(k) \lt f'(k)$$
Now I tried to look at these functions' monotony and maybe get something out of it.
For $k \in \mathbb N^*$, $f(x)$ is increasing and $f'(x)$ is decreasing. Now I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle f(k+1)-f(k)=\int_k^{k+1}\frac1{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 2):

You may just use the mean value theorem:

- $f(k+1) -f(k) = f'(\kappa)(k+1 - k) =f'(\kappa)=\frac{1}{1+\kappa^2}$ with $k <\kappa < k+1$

Hence,
$$\frac{1}{1+(k+1)^2} < f'(\kappa) = f(k+1) -f(k) < \frac{1}{1+k^2}$$